# CSS not working on table

Tags: css, html, html-table

The style settings i'm making for my table in my CSS file do not work in the html that i made

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ccffff;
}
h1 {
    font-family: verdana;
}
h2 {
    font-family: verdana;
}
h3 {
font-family: verdana;
}
h4 {
    color: red;
    font-family: verdana;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}
    table {
    width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
p  {
    font-family: verdana
}
#p01 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 200%;
}
p.error {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My second HTML</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mijn_eerste_css.css">
</head>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jan</td>
    <td>Jansens</td> 
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kees</td>
    <td>Pieters</td> 
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I put the exact same style settings in the HTML file like so:

```
<style>
table {
width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
```

It works just fine.
Why doesn't this work when it's in the CSS and what do I have to do to fix it?
(The CSS is linked properly, all the other style settings work just fine.)

Comment: Change those declarations to have !important after each one... table {
width: 100% !important;}.. like that, and let us know if it works.

Comment: See in browser inspector/developer tools what properties are loaded when you link your css. If you can't see them it means it is linked uncorrect, if they are crossed out it means something overrides it. There is also a possibility, you have to simply clear cache in browser.

Comment: @mayersdesign The following code did still not work. Or did I just did smoething wrong in there?

    table {
    width: 100% !important;
    }
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }
    th {
        text-align: left !important;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 15px !important;
    }

Comment: @Zydnar It seems like the properties indeed are not loading. when I make another css file with only the table properties it works fine. How come that the properties aren't loading in the first css? (the properties do not show in the browser dev tool)

Comment: I have no clue what happened but I somehow got it to work, thank you for commenting

Comment: Its hard to read so many lines of code from stackoverflow; can you please represent your code in snippet or jsfiddle, that would be really easy to understand your problem?

Answer (score -1):

I tried and it works just fine for me. it shows border also correctly.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mijn_eerste_css.css">.
```

I am not seeing any issue.
[image]

Comment: I've made a new css with only the properties that I posted here and it worked for me too, How come that the properties aren't loaded when I use the first css. I'll edit my post with the full css in a second.